# Reading Response From URL using HTTP WEB REQUEST

Tags: c#

I have to read response from http://www.subway.com/storelocator/default.aspx?zip=04416&country=USA .I have used following code but does not get all the response. instead of it gives response of error page Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string sUrl = "http://www.subway.com/storelocator/default.aspx?zip=04416&country=USA";
    XmlDocument rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlTextReader rssReader = new XmlTextReader(sUrl.ToString());

    WebRequest wrGETURL;
    wrGETURL = WebRequest.Create(sUrl);

    Stream objStream;
    objStream = wrGETURL.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(objStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    WebResponse wr = wrGETURL.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Response.Write(content);
   }
```

Comment: you want to send webrequest  from that url right ??

Comment: AFAIK you have to call wrGETURL.GetResponse() before using anything within the response

Answer (score 11):

I don't know what you want to do with `XmlTextReader` since returned content is `html` not `xml`, however setting UserAgent is enough to get the page.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.subway.com/storelocator/default.aspx?zip=04416&country=USA");
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
using (var resp = req.GetResponse())
{
    var html = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working now but if i need to get response for http://www.subway.com/storelocator/default.aspx?zip=04416&country=USA this url it not gives all store what i do to get all store from subway if we specify miles distance

Comment: @Janhavi Your question was `I have to read response from ..` and you got it. **You** should know why your url doesn't give the data you expect.

Answer (score 3):

```
Stream objStream;
StreamReader objSR;
System.Text.Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

string str = "http://domaninname.com/YourPage.aspx?name=" + "abc";
HttpWebRequest wrquest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(str);
HttpWebResponse getresponse = null;
getresponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrquest.GetResponse();

objStream = getresponse.GetResponseStream();
objSR = new StreamReader(objStream, encode, true);
string strResponse = objSR.ReadToEnd();
Response.Write(strResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

In just one line, with easier vb.net (that gets same performance as c#)

```
Return New System.IO.StreamReader(System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://urltogetthecontents.com").GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
```