# Injecting jQuery into WebBrowser control in WPF application

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have kinda simple problem. The task is to display just part of webpage loaded in `WebBrowser` control in WPF application. I looked up the problem on stack, but none of the solution helped me nor solved the problem. So what I learned is, that the easiest way to solve this is to inject a javascript/jquery function into the head of loaded page and then call it using `WebBrowser.InvokeScript` to do DOM manipulation, but whenever I call my function I get script error.

Here are functions that I tried, but none of them worked (I know nothing about jQuery or javascript so I don't really know how to approach the problem):

This one I found on stack (2nd answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220262/display-portion-of-a-website-into-a-web-browser))

```
function _changeDivs() {
    $('body >').hide(); 
    $('#dex1').show().prependTo('body');
}
```

I read the jQuery documentation on `prepend` and `prependTo` and from what i learned I tried: (here I just tried to get the script to not throw errors)

```
function _changeDivs() {
    $('body').prepend($('#dex1')); 
}
```

Simple `alert` works without problem. Here is code that I use to inject the script:

```
private void PageLoaded(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
        var webBrowser = (WebBrowser) sender;

        var doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
        var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head").Cast<mshtml.HTMLHeadElement>().First();
        var script = (mshtml.IHTMLScriptElement)doc.createElement("script");

        script.text = "function _changeDivs() { $('body >').hide(); $('#dex1').show().prependTo('body'); }";
        head.appendChild((mshtml.IHTMLDOMNode)script);

        webBrowser.InvokeScript("_changeDivs");
 }
```

In case you'd want to know when PageLoaded is called:

```
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += PageLoaded;
```

Comment: What error do you have... do you really have a `$ is undefined` or something like that?... What url are you loading into the web Browser control... do you own that site source? Try `alert($('body').prepend)` just to check if you get `function` or `[object]`...

Comment: I do not own the site source as I am loading facebook login page. When I try `alert($('body').prepend)` I still get error:
Error: Script error, Code: 0, URL: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/y6/r/BO2vbV5PICF.js, then it shows me COMException, but couldn't really read something useful there. Code error also was 0 so I couldn't even google the error by its code :/